# Restarting default cosos2d project causes "Thread 1: signal SIGBRT 1" error

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I want to create a game using Cocos2d in Iphone 6.1 simulator but when I create the default probject and tries to run it it starts up fine. But if I just restart it a couple of times i crashes and gives error

> med the Thread 1: signal SIGBRT

How do I solve this?
I'm using `4.6.2 with cocos2d 2.0. and ios simulator 6.0.`

Main looks like this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    int retVal = UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, @"AppController"); //Here I get the error Tread 1: signal abort
    [pool release];
    return retVal;
}
```

UI Applikation mail looks like this

```
0x9add89:  testb  %al, %al<br>
0x9add8b:  setne  %al<br>
0x9add8e:  movzbl %al, %eax<br>
0x9add91:  movl   %eax, (%esp)<br>
0x9add94:  calll  0xf3c038<br>              ; symbol stub for: GSEventInitialize<br>
0x9add99:  movl   7636317(%esi), %eax        //Here I get the error Tread 1: signal abort<br>
```

Comment: enable global exception breakpoint in xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade to Xcode 4.6.3, this should solve the Xcode bug. I always had such problem with 4.6.2 even with blank CocoaTouch projects.

Answer (score 0):

`SIGABRT` on that line of **`main`** means that your app is raising an `exception`, Click the “`Continue Program Execution`” button in the debugger bar to see that exception.